# I want to develop 2D animation games for ios,android,windows and blackberry

Tags: android, ios, windows, flash, blackberry

Right now I'm learning java(it will be finish in a month),
But don't know what to do next.
Some people tell me to learn adobe flash and related tools, but on internet I found that android doesn’t support  adobe flash.
I'm in totally in confusion.
What would be your suggestion?

Thank you for any help you can provide in this situation.

Comment: You cannot tell when you'll finish (learning) a programming language, believe me ;)

Comment: `Right now I'm learning java(it will be finish in a month)` - you will be the first person in history then.

Comment: true, but your comment doesn't help me.

Comment: Have a look at my answer then ;)

Comment: Android _does_ support game programming with Flash via Adobe Air...some of the most successful games on the Android platform are written with Flash and Air.

Comment: Adobe flash is not supported in Android browsers, but that's something completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with Java, have a look at [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/), which allows you to develop games for iOS, Android, Windows (not Windows Phone though, not sure whether you meant that) (BB via quick Android porting).

If you want to learn another language that is even more cross-platform, I'd suggest C++ for the fact it runs on nearly any platform.

A popular cross-platform game development framework in C++ is [Cocos2d-X](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/).